# Setting android 8888 Bitmap to all zeroes

Tags: java, android, graphics

I'm converting an OpenGL font renderer i've written for desktop programs into Android, and i have but one obstacle left, getting a Bitmap to have all its pixel values equal to (0, 0, 0, 0) so that only the areas i draw to are filled, the rest are completely transparent.

How is it possible to do this in Android? I've tried messing with SRC_ATOP color filters, but they don't actually seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `new Canvas(bitmap).drawARGB(0,0,0,0);`?